# How do I access ringtones I downloaded from an app on my computer?

Tags: ringtone

I got a new phone and am trying to move my old ringtones over to my new one, however when I get into the "Ringtones" folder on my computer, all I can see are the ringtones I edited myself. How do I access the ringtones I downloaded from an app? Is that even possible?